# Check time when file last update was completed in linux

Tags: linux, bash

Lets say `dir` directory has a file `f.txt`
`f.txt` is a heavy file updated by some external process, which takes 1 hour to complete.

The process started updating file at 1 PM, and final update was made at 2 PM. The process did not stop, or was killed in between.

When I run

```
cd dir
ls -l f.txt
```

should the expected time it show be 1 PM, or 2 PM?

If it shows 1 PM, is there a way I can get 2 PM displayed, i.e the time of last update?

Comment: Try `stat f.txt` and see if you can see more there

Comment: The last modified timestamp that is present in the `-l` flag should reflect the time when the file was closed by the writer. So 2pm. Are you seeing it as otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

> should the expected time it show be 1 PM, or 2 PM?

It depends on how your external process works and when you execute `ls -l f.txt`.

If the external process writes to a temporary file and then copy to `f.txt`, the `mtime` should be 1PM before the process exit and should be 2PM after the process exit.

If the process writes to `f.txt` directly. The `mtime` would be updated in real time.

Comment: ok, so you mean that after 2 PM, the mtime would be 2 PM if process writes to f.txt directly. Right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.